# How to access a variable from another function?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to access `myTimer` variable from `startTimer()` function inside my `backBtnPressed()` function. Basically i want to add this code `myTimer.invalidate()` inside my `backBtnPressed()` function. How can i achieve that?

```
    func startTimer() {
           var myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3.0,
                                     target: self,
                                     selector: #selector(scrollToNextCell),
                                     userInfo: nil,
                                     repeats: true)
    }

@IBAction func backBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        audioPlayer.stop()
    }
```

Comment: Add myTimer as member variable of the class.

Comment: I tried it. `var myTimer: Timer?` I added this outside of the function. But when i call it inside `backBtnPressed()` function it returns as `nil`

Comment: Can you please post your entire class code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple make your timer a property:

```
class MyClass {
    var timer: Timer?
    func startTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3.0, target: self, selector: #selector(scrollToNextCell), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @IBAction func backBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
           audioPlayer.stop()
           timer.//do something with timer
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I used to stupidly add var before myTimer inside function

Answer (score 1):

As it stands now, you cannot access `myTimer` variable outside `startTimer()`, because it is outside the scope. For that, you need to declare `myTimer` as a Class variable. Them, you need to initialize it, as you are doing, and them you can access whatever you want inside the Class. Also don't forget to call startTimer, or it will return nil.

It looks more or less like this:

```
class YourViewController: ViewController {

    var myTimer: Timer?
    //some of your functions here
    //...
    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         //...
         startTimer()
    }

    func startTimer() {
          myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3.0,
                                         target: self,
                                         selector: #selector(yourFunction),
                                         userInfo: nil,
                                         repeats: true)
    }

    @IBAction func backBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //do whatever you want
        myTimer.invalidate()
    }

}
```